# Distributed computing in Java, choice of application server

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi, distributed-computing, activiti

I am currently trying to incorporate an open-source business-process-engine ([Activiti](http://www.activiti.org)) into another application from my company but I am uncertain how to do this in a distributed manner. The application shall use certain function of Activiti that can not be provided by itself.

In a previous step I got this running locally by just importing the required jars of Activiti into the application project in Eclipse and making my function calls in the project after importing the right packages.

The next level now aims at running the application independently in its own Tomcat server and own database and to call certain functions from Activiti which is startet in its own JVM as well via network. Up to now I found RMI to be (probably) the right tool for this kind of distributed computing but I am uncertain on where to run Activiti. Another Tomcat server? Even though Activiti is not intended to have any frontend but merely to provide the necessary classes and methods to perform some actions that are by intention not provided by our application? How is the setup practically?

Honestly, I have not fully dug through the documentation of Tomcat yet, but I would appreciate even a short answer whether or not I am on the right track.

EDIT: To put it into a single question: On which platform can I run Activiti in my case?

Best,

Steffen

Comment: Your question rambles on a bit. Try to identify the one specific issue that's actually *blocking* your progress, and ask about how to resolve that issue. ("I don't know what to do now" is not a specific issue.)

Comment: "On which platform can I run Activiti in my case?" Going by the documentation which doesn't mention any other requirements, any Java EE server you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely run Activiti engine on independent Tomcat Server. You can than communicate with this standalone Activiti Engine using Activiti [REST API](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#N12B3A).
But bevare all processes runing on this standalone Activiti Engine need to have all utilized java delegates or spring beans etc. deployed together with Activiti Engine WAR package. They have to be in the same class loader as Activiti Engine itself.